# C++ what is meant by, at compile time?

Tags: c++

In C++ what is meant by, "at compile time"?

E.g "Or you could use templates, if you know the size at *compile time*."

Comment: It is used to refer to the time one compiles the program, not the time one executes it

Answer (score 1):

Something known "at compile time" is information available to the compiler (and, by extension, to you) at the point in time when the source code is compiled into a program. Such information can therefore be "baked into" the program, and certain aspects of the language are limited to this category of information.

For example:

- template arguments, which are all dealt with during the process of compilation itself;
- array dimensions, which are literally hardcoded into your compiled program rather than read as variables during program execution.

---

This is in contrast to things known only "at runtime"; this includes values input by a user or read from a file during execution, but can also be data that's written in your source code under some circumstances.

For example, a function `int x() { return 42; }` has a hardcoded return value, but if you call `x()` from a different translation unit (roughly: source file), the compiler won't *know* that the value is hardcoded when it compiles the call. Because this and other scenarios exist, the result of `x()` is not (and cannot be) considered by the language to be "constant".

(In this simple example, it can be alleviated using `inline` and `constexpr`.)

Answer (score 1):

See this list: [phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).  These phases all occur as part of the process of building an executable, they happen before the executable is executed.

"compile time" refers to the compiler processing those phases.  Sometimes people exclude phase 9 (calling it "link time" instead) but you typically judge from context whether they meant to include phase 9 or not.

For the example in your question, template instantiation, this occurs during phase 8.

Comment: interesting link.

Answer (score 0):

> "Or you could use templates, if you know the size at compile time."

This refers to: You know the size already when you write the code. You can write eg `42` because you know that the size will be `42`. Not at compile-time you know for example a value that is supplied by the user.

Suppose you have a

```
struct foo {
     // holds a container of bars
};
```

Two options:

You know the size of the container at compile time, that is, you know the size at the time you write the code. Then this is an option:

```
template <size_t size>
struct foo {
    std::array<bar,size> x;
};
```

Usage:

```
foo<42> f;
```

Or you do not know the size at compile-time, that is: The size is only known during execution. Then you cannot use `std::array` or a template with the size as parameter:

```
struct foo {
    std::vector<bar> x;
    foo(size_t size) : x(size) {}
}
```

Usage:

```
size_t size;
std::cin >> size;
foo f(size);
```